# Evaluating complex integral without contour integration

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

When calculating the integral
$$\int_{-\infty }^{0}  e^{x(\frac{a}{2} +it)} dx $$

where  $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ is some real parameter,  I first tried to write    $ e^{x(\frac{a}{2}+it)} =e^{x\frac{a}{2}}(cos(tx) + i sin(tx))  $   and then use partial integration on real and imaginary part to obtain the result.

Now I wonder if we can  just write: $\int_{-\infty }^{0}  e^{x(\frac{a}{2} +it)} dx = \frac{e^{x(\frac{a}{2} +it)}}{\frac{a}{2} +it} \bigg{|}_{-\infty}^{0}$ and then find limits when $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow 0$? Is there some theoretical exaplanation for doing this, something like Newton-Leibniz formula and how do I know in general if this can be done (evaluating integral in standard way, without contour integration). If it's not the case, do we need to apply contour integration and how?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: 1) Make a change of variables in order to integrate on $[0,+\infty)$ 2) Identify your integral as the Fourier Transform of a certain classical function.

Comment: @FShrike  a negative is bad.  Lower limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: @Jean Marie I know that this is Fourier transform of some function, but I don't want to use it. I want to calculate the integral directly, but I'm not sure how it can be done